# why my web login going to api.php routes instead web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-passport, laravel-7

I am new to Laravel,I have project on laravel wihout api and its login is working fine with web.php in routes, where in another project when I added passport api ,my web login redirects to api.php routes instead web routes. I made few required changes in different auth.php, providers file to configure **passport auth**

**Routes web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()){return Redirect::to('home');}
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.show');
Route::get('/company/{CompanyId}', 'CompanyController@index')->name('company.show');
```

**Routes Api.php**

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'],['cors', 'json.response']], function () {
    
    // ...

    // public routes
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\ApiAuthController@Login')->name('login.api');
    Route::post('/register','Auth\ApiAuthController@Register')->name('register.api');
    Route::post('/forgotpassword', 'Auth\ApiAuthController@ForgotPassword')->name('forgotpassword.api');
    

    // ...
});
```

**Login blade form redirection**

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
```

**Changes made middleware authanticate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

**App service provider**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
         'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();
        
        //
    }
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check your RouteServiceProvider.php file. You have to map the route file properly here

Comment: Thanks for response but RouteServiceProvider.php file is configured
**I have above added code from RouteServiceProvider.php file**

Comment: Add a group in your Api routes. Change `Route::group(['middleware' => ['api'],['cors', 'json.response']]` to `Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1, ...']` Your api routes must have `mysite.test/api/v1/...` to reach there. It will separate web request from api requests, unambiguous . It's a good practice to add `v1`, just in case you want to update your api in time. Once your api is used in other apps, it's hard to change the conventions you yourself have agreed to.

Comment: thanks for suggesting good practice,but it did not resolve the problem, though api working v1 prefix

Answer (score 0):

Because `$this->mapApiRoutes();` is above `$this->mapWebRoutes();` and your URLs (for example /login) is same the `Auth::routes();` route names,
See the below for understanding how basic authentication works:

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a name to your web login route like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()){return Redirect::to('home');}
    return view('auth.login')->name('login.web');
});
```

and see if it works.